# If content not published, hide also for admin

Tags: views, commerce, 9

I have a entity browser which list my produts. The products are shown only if they are published.

[image]

But for some reason, if the product was added before the filtered "publish" was set, the product is still displayed but only for the admin.

How can I prevent the admin to see it ?

EDIT :

For now, I've added a manual check in twig, but i think there's a cleaner way to do it

```
{% for produit in produits %}
   {% if produit['#commerce_product'].published %}
      {{ produit }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User accounts with permission to view unpublished content can view content.

Usually, the administrator role has the `Administer content` permission, so admins will see unpublished nodes.

To prevent this, go to `/admin/people/permissions`, scroll down to the **Node** category, and remove the `Administer content` permission as well as `Bypass access control` and any other permissions that may allow access to unpublished nodes (contrib modules can add permissions, so I can't list them all here).

If you only have one administrator role, you may want to create a separate role for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's it